# Import data from json file into webpage running locally from file: URL origin

Tags: javascript, json, import

I am viewing a webpage with its associated assets locally in my browser, so the URL origin (in Chrome) is `file:///`. The local file hierarchy looks like this:

```
./
index.html
script.js
data.json
```

`fetch` and `xhr` don't seem to work. How do I get the data in the .json file into the webpage (using vanilla JavaScript no libraries)?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery, then use `$.getJSON.`
 $.getJSON is asynchronous so you should do:

```
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
     document.write(json);        
     console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry—I forgot to mention that I cannot use any library dependencies in this situation, so jQuery won't work in this case. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve your assets using file:// you'll need to use relative URLs.  So fetch would be something like `fetch('data.json').then(data => //do something)`

The URL shouldn't start with a slash otherwise it looks like the file should be located up in your directory structure.  You can probably gain some understanding by looking at the JavaScript console of your browser...